# How to choose different dimensions for the video player in different views (views and video module)

Tags: 7, views, files

I've created a new content type with a video. For the content i choose as the default resolution 640*360. Now i need to create a grid with the views module and i'd like to be able to choose a different (smaller) resolution.

How can i do this?Do i need to do this programmatically or can i do this through the interface?